# Continuously check netstat output for a particular program

Tags: grep, netstat, watch

I have a android emulator running on port 5554. I want to continuously watch the netstat output concerning emulator stuff.

Right now I have to manually execute this command every time

```
sudo netstat -plant | grep emulator
```

I thought doing something like this would repeat above command automatically every 2 sec.

```
watch sudo netstat -plant | grep emulator
```

But instead it hangs the terminal. How to achieve such functionality ? Thanks

Comment: It's unrelated, but why do you use both `-l` and `-a`?

Comment: yeah I m only interested in listening port. 'plant' was easy to remember :P

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried those options? From the `man netstat` page:

```
-c, --continuous
  This will cause netstat to print the selected information every second continuously. 
delay
  Netstat will cycle printing through statistics every delay seconds.
```

In your case, you can just write:

```
sudo netstat -cplant | grep emulator
```

Comment: No I didn't try that :? . But how to make it display information regarding particular program name ?

Comment: The same way you did, with a grep. I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try that in terminal:

```
netstat -tuonp
```